# How can i send data of a Form Data to a child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form and created a FormData with the values inputed in the form. No i am trying to send this data in my formData variable to my child component which is a modal to use it there and render a modal.

This is my function which is creating a form data:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
e.preventDefault();
for( let [key, value] of formData.entries()){
  setData({
    key: key,
    value:value
  })
}
setIsOpen(true)

}
```

And this is what my component is rendering:

```
return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Modal 
      open={isOpen} 
      handleClose={handleClose} 
      data={data}     
      />

      <form className='contactForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <FormInput 
          key={input.id} 
          {...input} 
          value={values[input.name]} 
          onChange={onChange}
          />
        ))}
        <SubmitBtn handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />    
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

How can i send the data obtained in the form to my `<Modal/>`?

This is the whole file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import SubmitBtn from '../atoms/SubmitBtn';
import './ContactForm.css'
import './Modal.css'
import FormInput from '../molecules/FormInput'
import Modal from './Modal';


const ContactForm = () => {
  const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    key: '',
    value: ''
  })

  const [values, setValues ] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    confirmEmail: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const inputs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Name',
      required: true,
      pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]+$',
      errorMessage: 'Only letters are allowed '
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'lastname',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name',
      required: true,
      pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]+$',
      errorMessage: 'Only letters are allowed '
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Email',
      required: true,
      errorMessage: 'Invalid email'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'confirmEmail',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Confirm Email',
      required: true,
      pattern: values.email,
      errorMessage: 'Emails don´t match'

    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'message',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Message',
      required: true,
      errorMessage: 'This field cannot be empty'
    }
  ]

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    e.preventDefault();
    for( let [key, value] of formData.entries()){
      setData({
        key: key,
        value:value
      })
    }
    setIsOpen(true)
    
  }

  const handleClose = () =>{
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}); 
  }  

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Modal 
      open={isOpen} 
      handleClose={handleClose} 
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}    
      data={data}
      />

      <form className='contactForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <FormInput 
          key={input.id} 
          {...input} 
          value={values[input.name]} 
          onChange={onChange}
          />
        ))}
        <SubmitBtn handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />    
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

And this is my Modal where i want to render my data:

```
import React from 'react'

const Modal = ({ open, handleClose,data }) => {
  if(!open) return null

  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className="modal">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <input disabled>{data.key}</input>
                <input disabled></input>
                <input disabled></input>
                <input disabled></input>
                <input disabled></input>
                <button onClick={handleClose} >Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to the child component like this,

```
{isOpen && <Modal open={isOpen} handleClose={handleClose} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} data={fromData}/>}
```

**Note** You also need to store formData in a state so that you can pass it to the Modal

Comment: How would you do to store the formData? `const [data, setDate] = useState([])` ??

Comment: See how i edited my question please. I stored the formData in a object using useState and passed it to my modal but i get this error. `input is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: the error is stemming from this line <input disabled>{data.key}</input>. Change it to <input value={data.key} disabled />.

Comment: Sort of because it always showing the same value for the different inputs. How can i make for my input to identify which value to show?

Comment: I wish I could've answered your follow-up question but I can't really make sense of what you are doing inside your code. So you can mark my answer as accepted if you want to